Connect HTTPS and HTTP in AWS
I have deployed my frontEnd(React) to Amplify and also have deployed my backEnd(Springboot) to EC2 by myself.
I have tested that I can send values to my BackEnd(EC2) It works fine as attached image.
I was able to send values from my local host to EC2 server.
The thing is Amplify is HTTPS and my EC2 is HTTP. Would you please help me How to connect Amplify and EC2? As I am new to deploying to AWS, I need your hints.
Thank you so much.
enter image description here
